# Firestore collection missing after export

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I export my database like this:

```
gcloud firestore export gs://xx.appspot.com/asdcx
gsutil -m cp -r gs://xx.appspot.com/asdcx ../../../
firebase emulators:start --import ../../../asdcx
```

This used to work quite well. But since a few days after changing some fields I can't get one of the collections of the database to export at all. The other collections export and work successfully. The collection that doesn't work is quite large (50k documents). I see it in the web UI yet if I export it this way and try to find it in the emulator UI - it's not there and I can't access it locally. I see it on the web UI for firestore but if I try accessing it with my code that also doesn't work. Why does that happen?

Edit: FB debug file shows this

> Failed to send a new message due to too many pending messagings in the back channel (10001). May need enable flow control.

I also noticed that the firebase export produces a single file of 140 mb -> output-0. Usually it was in more chunks of those output files. I don't really understand how to set that but it seems to be set automatically and it might be the reason why I can't load the data (maybe too much data in a single chunk?)

Comment: Hi, 
Just to be clear with your scenario, can you confirm the following: 
After executing the export command, you can see the “export” completed for the collection of 50k documents on your bucket?
Which versions of “gcloud” & “gsutil” are you using on your local machine?
Are you trying to download the export to be used on your emulator?

Comment: @MathewBellamy Yes, the export completes and I can see it in the google console app. But, it contains a single export output-0 file. For some reason today after I exported it again it now has multiple chunks of those output files. My gsutil verion is 4.57. I don't know how to check the gcloud one.

Comment: Hi @ChristoS.Christov, what is the size of output-0 file? Can you also check which collections are in your bucket? This only to verify if the collection you want to export is still there. To get "gcloud" version number, use the following command: gcloud version. You can refer to these [gsutil doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/update) & [gcloud doc](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/components/update)
Latest version now for gcloud is: 336.0.0 and for gsutil is 4.61. If you have an outdated version, can you update them and try again? please.

Comment: Hi Mathew, I still encounter this problem.  

Google Cloud SDK 342.0.0
bq 2.0.68      
core 2021.05.21
gsutil 4.62

I can confirm that the collections are still visible in the web ui